# Is there a reason why arrays in memory 'go' down while the function stack usually 'goes' up?

Tags: buffer, memory-management, cpu-architecture, buffer-overflow

Though the actual implementation is platform specific, this idea is the cause for potentially dangerous buffer overflows. For example,

```
-------------
|   arr[0]  | \
-------------  \
|   arr[1]  |   -> arr[3] is local to a function
-------------  /
|   arr[2]  | /
-------------
| frame ptr |
-------------
|  ret val  |
-------------
|  ret addr |
-------------
|    args   |
-------------
```

My question is, is there a reason why the local array, for lack of a better verb, flows down? Instead, if the array was to flow up, wouldn't it significantly reduce the number of buffer overflow errors that overwrite the return address?

Granted, by using threads, one could overwrite the return address of a function that the current one has called. But lets ignore it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array on the stack works just like an array on the heap, i.e. its index increases as the memory address increases.

The stack grows downwards (towards lower addresses) instead of upwards, which is the reason for the array going in the opposite direction of the stack. There is some historic reason for that, probably from the time when the code, heap and stack resided in the same memory area, so the heap and the stack grew from each end of the memory.

Comment: This answer is the best.  You can learn more about memory layout here: http://dirac.org/linux/gdb/02a-Memory_Layout_And_The_Stack.php  The stack and the heap grow in opposite directions to make the most out of unused memory address space.

Answer (score 0):

I can't cite a source for this, but I believe it's so you can step through memory. Consider `while *p++` or something along those lines.

Now, you could just as easily say `while *p--` but I guess if they had a choice, they'd rather overwrite someone else's data than their own return value :) Talk about a 'greedy algorithm' (har har)

Comment: That was the reason I came up with too. But surely it wouldn't be too hard for the compiler to make the appropriate adjustments. I guess scalability can be an issue here.

Comment: What do you mean by compiler make appropriate adjustments?

Comment: I think he meant for the assembler to make the necessary adjustments for how the stack was organized

Comment: Say arr was of type int and we are working on a little endian computer, the individual bytes for an int are in reverse order. But when you access an int, the compiler makes the necessary 'adjustments' and gives you the answer. Likewise, as a start, the compiler could interpret arr[10] as arr[-10]. But you do make a point with *p++

Answer (score 0):

To have a subarray you usually pass just a pointer to it. Any indexing operation would need to know the size of the array, unless you'd like to make all of memory index backwards -- but if you would, you'd just get yourself in the same situation :P.